# Disjoint union?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Consider $n$ sets $A_1,...,A_n$. Futhermore consider the set of indices $\{i_1,..,i_k\}\subset \{1,..,n\}$ and its complement  $\{j_1,..,j_m\}$with $m=n-k$. Thus
$$\bigcap_{l=1}^k A_{i_l} = \bigcup_{k_1,...,k_m\in \{1,c\}}\left(\bigcap_{l=1}^k A_{i_l} \cap \bigcap_{s=1}^m A^{k_j}_{j_s}\right) $$

with  $A^1=A$. $A^c$ refers to the complement of $A$.

Why should this be a disjoint union?

Comment: Question title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For brevity let $B=\bigcap_{\ell=1}^kA_{i_\ell}$. Let $k_1,\ldots,k_m,k_1',\ldots,k_m'\in\{1,c\}$, and assume that there is some $t\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$ such that $k_t=1$ and $k_t'=c$; we want to show that

$$\left(B\cap\bigcap_{s=1}^mA_{j_s}^{k_j}\right)\cap\left(B\cap\bigcap_{s=1}^mA_{j_s}^{k_j'}\right)=\varnothing\,.\tag{1}$$

And

$$\begin{align*}
\left(\bigcap_{s=1}^mA_{j_s}^{k_{j_s}}\right)\cap\left(\bigcap_{s=1}^mA_{j_s}^{k_{j_s}'}\right)&=\bigcap_{s=1}^m\left(A_{j_s}^{k_{j_s}}\cap A_{j_s}^{k_{j_s}'}\right)\\
&\subseteq A_t^{k_{j_t}}\cap A_t^{k_{j_t}'}\\
&=A_t\cap A_t^c\\
&=\varnothing\,,
\end{align*}$$

from which $(1)$ follows immediately.

Comment: Thank you very much. I get it. I still wonder why is it possible to rewrite $\bigcap_{l=1}^k A_{i_l}$ in such a way?

Comment: @Alif: You’re very welcome. Draw a Venn diagram for a small $n$, say $n=3$ or $n=4$, and you’ll see that it’s just writing that intersection as the union of its ‘pieces’.

Comment: I got it for $n=3$:) Is there also an analytic proof?

Comment: @Alif: I’m not sure what you mean by *analytic proof* in this context.

Comment: I mean something like your answer?